# authentication on python for wsgi application

Tags: python, wsgi

I try to make simple wsgi application without any frameworks, only standard library (wsgiref). And now I looking for simple way to make authentication in my application. How I can make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple authentication module here: https://github.com/comamitc/py-userauth

It should give you some ideas to work on if you want to write your own to handle encryption of the password, password matching, complexity checking, registration, etc.

I would also check out Django's authentication mechanism as it's pretty widely accepted and really fleshed out.

Unfortunately, my example doesn't contain any wsgi specific code, but just some general guidelines to setting up your own authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use any frameworks or libraries, you just have to implement it manually: use some kind of storage for credentials, generate forms, check passwords preferrably using salted hashes, create and store session identifiers in cookies and so on.

But maybe if it's not intended to be a public application, you can go with just basic HTTP auth implemented in Apache, nginx or any other web server you are using to launch your wsgi app.